# Hide a custom iPhone control when another portion of the screen is tapped

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

My problem is thus: I've created a custom view, a numeric keypad, that I display when a button is pressed. When anywhere else on the screen is tapped, I want to hide the keypad.

I solved the problem by overriding touchesBegan:withEvent. Then a hit test tells me if the numeric keypad was pressed. As long as the keypad wasn't pressed, I hide it (by setting its hidden property to YES).

It works, but I don't like it. Its not very clean. My other option is to have a view controller for the numeric keypad and display it as a modal view controller. The keypad view would have a transparent background. I don't like this method either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use gestures to catch touch events and allow them to be used within the controls/views as well `cancelsTouchesInView = NO`. Tap-Gesture outside of your keypad -> hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to have an invisible UIButton that you add to the view when the keypad comes up and remove along with the keypad when it is tapped.

Of course, the tap you get on the UIButton will prevent you from using that tap for anything else, so your interface wouldn't work while the keypad is there.

Comment: No need for a button - a UIControl would do. But I would go for gestures instead.